# Laravel: how to simplify artisan commands?

Tags: laravel, migration, command, laravel-artisan

I want to simplify the following artisan commands because I have several databases and the migrations for each database are stored in a separate folder.

```
php artisan make:migration {{name}} --path=/database/migrations/{{folder}}

php artisan migrate:rollback  --path=/database/migrations/{{folder}}
```

to

```
php artisan make:migration {{name}} {{folder}}

php artisan migrate:rollback {{folder}}
```

Is this possible and if so how can I implement it?

Comment: You can [write your own commands](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands) that call other artisan commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not an option in the Laravel commands, a way to implement this yourself is by [writing you own commands that call other artisan commands](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands).

To do so, in your terminal write, for example, `php artisan make:command MigrateWithPath` to create a new command at `app/Console/Commands/MigrateWithPath.php`. Then, you can call the vanilla implementation Laravel provides at `(vendor\laravel\framework\src) \Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand` but then in a way that you specify.

Be sure though that the name of your new command needs to be different from the Laravel one, to prevent recursions. Therefore, I have prefixed the name with `app:` to be like `app:make:migration`, but feel free to use something else.

Take a look at the following suggestion:

```
class MigrateWithPath extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:make:migration {name : The name of the migration}
        {folder? : The location where the migration file should be created}';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->call('make:migration', [
            'name' => $this->argument('name'),
            '--path' => '/database/migrations/' . $this->argument('folder'),
        ]);

        return 0;
    }
```

Then do the same for the rollback command.

Comment: However, I would like to use the same name as the original command. Do you have an idea of how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Elisaveta I suppose you then have to implement the entire code yourself instead of leaning on `$this->call('make:migration', ...)` because that is the part that initiates the recursion. Unless there is a way to untangle them with some rename or absolute path to keep them apart that I am not aware of. If so, I encourage others to write their answer.